# Deep clone a imported property in Vuejs3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have obeject which looks like below which is stored in a seperate file and later imported as import from "path"
into the vue component.

```
const myTemplate = 
{
    a:{
        key11: undefined,
        key12: undefined
    },
    b:{
        key21: undefined,
        key22: undefined
    }
    
}
```

Inside the component i am using this `myTemplate` object to create new data property

```
<script>
    data(){
        getfields: myTemplate
    }
</script>
```

In script i loop over the `myTemplate` and assign it with the prop coming from the parent component which holds the value of the `key11, key12 ,key21 ,...`so on

Purpose of `myTemplate` is to act as base/standard format which collect the data from the incoming prop.

Later on `getfields` is looped over by `v-for` in  `<template>` tag to display the content

I send props `{key11: somevalue1, key12: somevalue2}` to my child component matches the keys inside the `myTemplate` object uses the methods inside this child component to update the same  keys in `getfields`

**end result:**

```
{
    a:{
        key11: somevalue1,
        key12: somevalue2
    },
    b:{
        key21: undefined,
        key22: undefined
    }   
}
```

**Problem:**

In case of objects, JS copies the references and it alters my `myTemplate` object as well.

I want to have my `myTemplate` intact and cannot be altered in any way if the `getfields` gets changed.

**What i've  tried:**

1. Deep clone   `const getfields : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myTemplate))` --> dint work for me because
   `myTemplate` is `Object of objects`
2. Tried the dynamic import in the hope that would help but it dint

   let self= this
   import("path")
   .then((data) =>{
   self.getfields = data.default
   })

Comment: You should try with `Object.assign({},myTemplate)` instead just `myTemplate` here `getfields: myTemplate`

Comment: `JSON.parse/stringify` *does* clone nested objects as long as it doesn't have circular references. What's the issue you encounter with that?

Comment: Ohh Yes we can use the in recursive way `JSON.parse/stringify`. I wonder why i dint thought of that before.
Thanks!!

Comment: @NikleshRaut    `Object.assign({},myTemplate)`  will create a shallow copy ie if you have object inside object this will copy the reference of inside object instead of actual value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use Lodash library to clone the object with **_.cloneDeep()**

E.g:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

.
.
.

```
const getfields = _.cloneDeep(myTemplate)
```

It's the library I use with Vuejs for preventing those unexpected modifications in the original element because it just clones it.

Official documentation: https://lodash.com/docs/

If you have limited access to internet, you should use VanillaJs to create the clone function, look at this https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/deep-clone-with-vanilla-js-5ef16e0b365c

Comment: Application is under vpn and I have limited access to npm libs and the lodash needs login from GitHub which is restricted in my workplace

Comment: Have you tried to clone with Vanilla JS? Not aditional plugins needed. I tested it and it works as expected
https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/deep-clone-with-vanilla-js-5ef16e0b365c

Comment: That's great article. Can you edit you answer and put the referal link to it.
I'll accept the answer

Comment: Done the change in the answer! @Ruben